# Traveling to Mexico with green card

Tags: mexico

I'm a permanent resident and want to travel to Mexico by bus, do I need a matricula to travel or what documentation will I need?

Comment: Are you a citizen of Mexico?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.